# Database Logon Failed when executing my Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Database logon failed.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Database logon failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 31:         report.Load(Server.MapPath("Purchases2.rpt")); Line
>   32:         report.SetParameterValue("PurchDate",
>   DateTime.Parse(txtPurch.Text)); Line 33:
>   report.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
>   Response, true, Line 34:             "Purchases Report"); Line 35:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Isidro\Desktop\MRP\Reports\Purchases.aspx.cs
>   Line: 33
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x8004100f): Database logon failed.]
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions
>   pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext) +0
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext) +414
>
> [LogOnException: Database logon failed.]
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception
>   e) +332
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext) +947
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext) +654
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions
>   options) +92
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportOptions
>   options, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String
>   attachmentName) +96
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType
>   formatType, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String
>   attachmentName) +119    Reports_Purchases.btnMaterials_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Isidro\Desktop\MRP\Reports\Purchases.aspx.cs:33
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +108
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +31    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3466

BACK END CODE:

```
void GetReport()
    {
        ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Purchases2.rpt"));
        report.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "benilde", @"MJ\ISIDRO", "MRPsys");
    }

protected void btnMaterials_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("Purchases2.rpt"));
    report.SetParameterValue("PurchDate", DateTime.Parse(txtPurch.Text));
    report.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true,
        "Purchases Report");

    crvReport.ReportSource = report;
    crvReport.DataBind();
}
```

Additional Info:
[image]

Comment: You are setting database logon in GetReport method but you are not using that method in button click event. You should use report.SetDatabaseLogon in button click too.

Comment: Great! It's now working. Thanks for your help.